# Jest.fn().mockReturnValue returns undefined

Tags: jestjs, mocking, babel-jest

Below mentioned mocked function when used in a file called **useFirestore** gives the following error: **Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined**.

**firebase.js**

```
import Firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {'// Firebase config'};

const firebase = !Firebase.apps.length ? Firebase.initializeApp(config) : Firebase.app;

export const { serverTimestamp } = Firebase.firestore.FieldValue;

export default firebase;
```

**setupTests.js**

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';


jest.mock('./firebase', () => ({
  storage: jest.fn(),
  firestore: jest.fn().mockReturnedValue({
    collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    orderBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    onSnapshot: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  }),
}));
```

**Custom Hook**

```
import firebase from '../firebase';

function useFirestore(collectionName) {
  const [docs, setDocs] = React.useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = firebase
      .firestore() // logs cannot read property collection of undefined
      .collection(collectionName)
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot(
        (snapshot) => {
          setDocs(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })));
          setLoading(false);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    return unsub;
  }, [collectionName]);

  return {
    docs,
    loading,
  };
}

export default useFirestore;
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    '!<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '!<rootDir>/coverage/',
    '!<rootDir>/build/',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: { '\\.(css|scss)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils/__mocks__/stylemock.js' },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js'],
};
```

As mentioned the above configuration returns undefined. However, when I change the mock implemenation of **firestore** to the following, it works correctly.

```
jest.mock('./firebase', () => ({
  storage: jest.fn(),
  firestore: () => ({ // not using jest.fn() and mockReturnValue
    collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    orderBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    onSnapshot: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  }),
}));
```

Please guide if anything's wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply a typo my friend! No such thing as `mockReturnedValue` on type `jest.Mock`, you probably want to use `mockReturnValue`.